# How does a photon get created without the use of other photons?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons

I understand how photons get produced with the different energy levels and so on however I couldn't find an explanation of how these photons get produced with other forms of energie, other than photons like for example when the first ever photon was created. I would appreciate the help!

Comment: Didn't Newton create the first photon?

Comment: It all comes from the Big Bang, 13 or so billion years ago.  Matter/particles condensed into stars .... many star nuclear processes produce photons .... eventually our planet earth turned photon energy into life ......

Answer (score 0):

We know from experiments that photons exist and in accumulation builds up the classical electromagnetic light . This [classroom experiment](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) shows how an accumulation of random looking photon interactions with a screen add up to the interference pattern of light.

[image: singlphot]

> an explanation of how these photons get produced with other forms of energy, other than photons

This means that however classical electrodynamics predicts that light is created, this light will be made up of photons. For example accelerated charges produce light , as shown in [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wF8vLZ9ceb0) . So photons are produced since they are the building blocks of classical electromagnetic light.